# SP2010 Using SPLongOperation in Dialog Boxes

Tags: development

I would like to have the following behavior.
After clicking the submit button in a custom layout page, a dialog box opens showing the SPLongOperation page. After the operation is done my custom success page is shown in the dialog box.

My solution would have the following structure:

InputForm.aspx (Cust. App. page)
- with function OpenDialog() { options.url = '/_layouts/ProcessInputForm.aspx'; }
ProcessInputForm.aspx (Cust. App. page)
ProcessInputForm.aspx.cs  With all the code that need to be executed in between the SPLongOperation statements

I'm only doubting how to transfer my form inputs.
Do I need to pass them as parmeters of my OpenDialog() function or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your parameters as querystring parameters. Inject your javascript with some server side code or try the following (not sure if that works though... haven't test it yet)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

   //Dialog opening 
   function OpenDialog() { 
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions(); 
    options.url = "/_layouts/ProcessInputForm.aspx?Parameter1=<% GetParam1(); %>&Parameter2=<% GetParam2();"; 
    options.width = 500; 
    options.height = 400; 
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback); 
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options); 
    } 

var messageId; 

  // Dialog callback 
    function CloseCallback(result, target) { 
    if(result === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) { 
        alert("OK was clicked!"); 
    } 
    if(result === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) { 
        alert("Cancel was clicked!");         
    } 
}
```